Notation question related to an exercise from Dummit & Foote in polynomial rings section
Background

Exercise:  Let $F[x,y_1,y_2,\ldots]$ be the polynomial ring in the infinite set of variables $x,y_1,y_2,\ldots$ over the field $F$, and let $I$ be the ideal $(x-{y_1}^2, y_1-{y_2}^2,\ldots,y_i-{y_{i+1}}^2,\ldots)$ in this ring.  Define $R$ to be the ring $F[x,y_1,y_2,\ldots]/I$, so that in $R$ the square of each $y_{i+1}$ is $y_i$ and ${y^2}_1=x$ modulo $I$, i.e., $x$ has a $2^i$th root, for every $i$.  Denote the image of $y_i$ in $R$ as $x^{\frac{1}{2^i}}$.  Let $R_n$ be the subring of $R$ generated by $R$ and $x^{\frac{1}{2^i}}$.


$(a)$  Prove that $R_1\subseteq R_2\subseteq\cdots$ and that $R$ is the union of all $R_n$, i.e., $R=\cup_{i=1}^{\infty}R_n$.

Questions
I would like to know in the above quoted exercise, the portion where it states: "Denote the image of $y_i$ in $R$ as $x^{\frac{1}{2^i}}$.  Let $R_n$ be the subring of $R$ generated by $R$ and $x^{\frac{1}{2^i}}$.", I am not sure what is meant by:  the image of $y_i$ in $R$ as $x^{\frac{1}{2^i}}$?  For the next part of the quoted portion: "Let $R_n$ be the subring of $R$ generated by $R$ and $x^{\frac{1}{2^i}}$", does it mean in math notation:  $R_n=R[x^{\frac{1}{2^i}}]$?
Thank you in advance.


The grammar is "denote (the image of $y_i$ in $R$) as $x^{ \frac{1}{2^i} }$". That is, we have a quotient map $\varphi : F[x, y_i] \to R$ and the author is saying that $x^{\frac{1}{2^i}}$ is notation for $\varphi(y_i)$. The point of this notation is that $\varphi(y_i)$ has been defined to be a square root of $\varphi(y_{i-1})$, so the notation "makes sense," e.g. these numbers multiply with each other in the expected way.

There are two typos here. It should say "let $R_{\color{red}{i}}$ be the subring of $R$ generated by $\color{red}{F}$ and $x^{\frac{1}{2^{i}}}$," so $R_i = F[x^{\frac{1}{2^i}}] \subset R$. There is also a typo in the last statement which should read $R = \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} R_{\color{red}{i}}$.



thank you so much for the clarification.  I feel that abstract algebra stretches the limit of my reading comprehension abilities with languages.

Yes, that first bit was a little unclear if you're not used to how these constructions go. It would maybe be clearer if they had said "by" instead of "as," and even clearer (although clunkier) if they had explicitly named the quotient map. Or just said something like "let $x^{\frac{1}{2^i}}$ denote the image of $y_i$ in $R$."

And of course the typo is entirely the fault of the authors and not any fault of yours!
